# Error at some items from material

Tags: angular

When i am trying to build the applicattion i got theses errors, i have already tried so many things but couldn't find the reason

package.json

"@angular/animations": "^4.4.4"

"@angular/cdk": "^5.1.1"

"@angular/common": "^4.4.4"

"@angular/compiler": "^4.4.4"

"@angular/core": "^4.4.6",
   "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.9"

"@angular/forms": "^4.4.4"

"@angular/http": "^4.4.4"

"@angular/material": "^5.2.3"

"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.4"

"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.4"

"@angular/router": "^4.4.4"

"cli": "^1.0.1"

"core-js": "^2.4.1"

"node": "^9.4.0"

"nodejs": "0.0.0"

"rxjs": "^5.1.0"

"zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },

Error at git bash

```
ERROR in Cannot determine the module for class MatCellDef in D:/Angular/node_modules/@angular/material/table/typings/cell.d.ts! Add MatCellDef to the NgModule to fix it.
Cannot determine the module for class MatHeaderCellDef in D:/Angular/node_modules/@angular/material/table/typings/cell.d.ts! Add MatHeaderCellDef to the NgModule to fix it.
Cannot determine the module for class MatColumnDef in D:/Angular/node_modules/@angular/material/table/typings/cell.d.ts! Add MatColumnDef to the NgModule to fix it.
Cannot determine the module for class MatHeaderCell in D:/Angular/node_modules/@angular/material/table/typings/cell.d.ts! Add MatHeaderCell to the NgModule to fix it.
Cannot determine the module for class MatCell in D:/Angular/node_modules/@angular/material/table/typings/cell.d.ts! Add MatCell to the NgModule to fix it.
Cannot determine the module for class MatTable in D:/Angular/node_modules/@angular/material/table/typings/table.d.ts! Add MatTable to the NgModule to fix it.
Cannot determine the module for class MatHeaderRowDef in D:/Angular/node_modules/@angular/material/table/typings/row.d.ts! Add MatHeaderRowDef to the NgModule to fix it.
Cannot determine the module for class MatRowDef in D:/Angular/node_modules/@angular/material/table/typings/row.d.ts! Add MatRowDef to the NgModule to fix it.
Cannot determine the module for class MatHeaderRow in D:/Angular/node_modules/@angular/material/table/typings/row.d.ts! Add MatHeaderRow to the NgModule to fix it.
Cannot determine the module for class MatRow in D:/Angular/node_modules/@angular/material/table/typings/row.d.ts! Add MatRow to the NgModule to fix it.
Cannot determine the module for class MatCheckboxRequiredValidator in D:/Angular/node_modules/@angular/material/checkbox/typings/checkbox-required-validator.d.ts! Add MatCheckboxRequiredValidator to the NgModule to fix it.
Cannot determine the module for class MatAccordion in D:/Angular/node_modules/@angular/material/expansion/typings/accordion.d.ts! Add MatAccordion to the NgModule to fix it.
Cannot determine the module for class MatExpansionPanel in D:/Angular/node_modules/@angular/material/expansion/typings/expansion-panel.d.ts! Add MatExpansionPanel to the NgModule to fix it.
Cannot determine the module for class MatStepLabel in D:/Angular/node_modules/@angular/material/stepper/typings/step-label.d.ts! Add MatStepLabel to the NgModule to fix it.
Cannot determine the module for class MatStep in D:/Angular/node_modules/@angular/material/stepper/typings/stepper.d.ts! Add MatStep to the NgModule to fix it.
Cannot determine the module for class MatStepper in D:/Angular/node_modules/@angular/material/stepper/typings/stepper.d.ts! Add MatStepper to the NgModule to fix it.
Cannot determine the module for class MatHorizontalStepper in D:/Angular/node_modules/@angular/material/stepper/typings/stepper.d.ts! Add MatHorizontalStepper to the NgModule to fix it.
Cannot determine the module for class MatVerticalStepper in D:/Angular/node_modules/@angular/material/stepper/typings/stepper.d.ts! Add MatVerticalStepper to the NgModule to fix it.
Cannot determine the module for class MatStepperNext in D:/Angular/node_modules/@angular/material/stepper/typings/stepper-button.d.ts! Add MatStepperNext to the NgModule to fix it.
Cannot determine the module for class MatStepperPrevious in D:/Angular/node_modules/@angular/material/stepper/typings/stepper-button.d.ts! Add MatStepperPrevious to the NgModule to fix it.
Cannot determine the module for class MatTabLabel in D:/Angular/node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/tab-label.d.ts! Add MatTabLabel to the NgModule to fix it.
Cannot determine the module for class MatTabBodyPortal in D:/Angular/node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/tab-body.d.ts! Add MatTabBodyPortal to the NgModule to fix it.
ERROR in ./UI/src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'D:\Angular\UI\src'
 @ ./UI/src/main.ts 3:0-74
 @ multi ./UI/src/main.ts


import { MatTableModule, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
import {
    MatToolbarModule, MatSidenavModule, MatButtonModule,
    MatListModule, MatStepperModule, MatInputModule, MatSelectModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatPaginatorModule, MatTabsModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
} from '@angular/material';
```

i have already written the imports

Comment: Update angular packages to `5` or greater

Comment: go to https://material.angular.io and click on one of the examples. it will open up in stackblitz. https://stackblitz.com/angular/roqolklrxod?file=app%2Fcard-overview-example.ts